# Get IVsExpansion object from IWpfTextView, ITextBuffer or ITextDocument

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, code-snippets, visual-studio-extensions

I want insert a custom snippet into an XML file from code within an extension package.

Does anybody know how to get an IVsExpansion object when I have an IWpfTextView, ITextBuffer or ITextDocument?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.textmanager.interop.ivsexpansion.aspx

Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you also post this the other day on the MSDN VS Extensibility forum?  If so I answered there with a possible approach (I haven't tried it and I am not an editor dev):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/c43699d3-4ed1-4a68-b1c8-d207efc98a04

In short I believe you can use the IVsEditorAdapterFactoryService to map from ITextBuffer -> IVsTextBuffer, and MSDN says IVsExpansion is implemented by the same object that implements IVsTextBuffer so if you cast the IVsTextBuffer to IVsExpansion it should succeed.

Ryan